# What part of speech is "Lend a hand"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

What part of speech is "lend a hand"? I know it is not an idiom or a metaphor because it is literal not symbolic.

Comment: Probably a *verb phrase*, with **lend** being the verb and **a hand** being its object. And it is both an idiom and a metaphor, as far as I understand. Unless someone literally *lends a hand* to some other one, for instance, for transplantation purposes (with a return at a later date).

Comment: Yeah, a literal meaning would be infinitesimally rare.

Comment: One can certainly lend a hand if the "hand" is used in the meaning "servant" or "helper" (see "deck hand" with respect to boating/shipping).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CopperKettle says, "to lend a hand" is a verb phrase meaning to aid someone in a task:

Some examples:

> Jim could not open the jar so I lent a hand and opened it for him.

Which means the same as:

> Jim could not open the jar so I helped and opened it for him.

Or:

> "What are you doing?"
>   "Phillipa is painting her wall, so I am lending a hand"

Which means the same as:

> "What are you doing?"
>   "Phillipa is painting her wall, so I am helping her"